# WCF Certificate Authentication Clarification

Tags: wcf, security

WCF certificate credential over transport security needs client to send pfx file in order to work properly.

pfx files contain both public and private key.

I'm pretty sure client should not share its private key.

What did I get wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

WCF Client do not send pfx file.

It needs both public and private key in order to authenticate, but only public key is sent during authentication protocol.